# How to Make Questions Appear One at a Time with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a React webapp that involves a quiz, and I want to make the questions appear one at a time instead of all on the same page (note that this code is pretty rudimentary). Here's what I have so far in my JS files:

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './index.css' ;
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Question.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Row, Card, Button} from "react-bootstrap";

class Question extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      feedback: ''
    }
  }

  handleSelect = (answer) => {
    if (answer === this.props.answer) {
      this.setState({feedback: `You selected ${answer}. Correct`});
    }
    else {
      this.setState({feedback: `You selected ${answer}. WRONG`});
    }
  }

  

  render() {
    const {questionNumber, question, answer, answerChoices} = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
      <Card className = "question-card">

        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Img variant="top" src="https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/photo/67586673.cms" />
          <Card.Title>Question #{questionNumber}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Text>
            {question}
          </Card.Text>
          <Row className = "justify-content-md-center">
            <Button variant="primary" className = "answer-choice-button" onClick = {() => this.handleSelect('A')}>A. {answerChoices[0]}</Button>
            <Button variant="primary" className = "answer-choice-button" onClick = {() => this.handleSelect('B')}>B. {answerChoices[1]}</Button>
          </Row>
          <Row className = "justify-content-md-center">
            <Button variant="primary" className = "answer-choice-button" onClick = {() => this.handleSelect('C')}>C. {answerChoices[2]}</Button>
            <Button variant="primary" className = "answer-choice-button" onClick = {() => this.handleSelect('D')}>D. {answerChoices[3]}</Button>
          </Row>
        </Card.Body>
     </Card>

      <div className = "question-feedback">{this.state.feedback}</div>
     </div>

  )
  }

}

export default Question;
```

I saw a few other questions earlier trying to do something similar - basically, they made a questionCount variable and then hid all of the questions and revealed them one at a time (sorry, I'm a JS noob). However, I had difficulties incorporating this into my code because I don't actually have arrays of questions, just divs. Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: as @Arjun Nair said you need to provide a little more info about the structure or format in which the questions are present. Also even if you have divs, you can still make use of array